# How to prove that $2^n \equiv n \pmod p\:$ iff $n=(p-1)(kp-1), k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, examples-counterexamples

Okay, I am solving equivalence $2^n \equiv n \mod p$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and odd prime $p$.

I got that if $n = (p-1)(kp-1)$ then we have a solution (using Fermat's little theorem)

But is it true that only such $n$'s are appropriate? Is there a way to prove that?

Comment: You should easily find lots of counterexamples for small primes $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=5$ and $p=3$ you have $2^5\equiv5\pmod{3}$ but $5$ is not divisible by $p-1=2$.

Comment: I see... But is it possible then to solve $2^n \equiv n \mod p$? I mean explicit value of $n$ expressed through $p$

Comment: @math-traveler In general there are many solutions. If $2^n\equiv n\pmod{p}$ and $m\equiv n\pmod{p(p-1)}$ then also $2^m\equiv m\pmod{p}$. The number of solutions is simply the number of distinct powers of $2$ mod $p$. I doubt you will find any explicit expression for these values of $n$ in terms of $p$.